# React Global Auth State becomes undefined after redirection

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-hooks, axios, jwt

I am building a chat application with React and am facing an issue related to my authentication logic. After a successful login, I store the access token in a global state called 'auth'. But after being redirected to the chat page, the 'auth' state becomes undefined.

1. Post login, I can see that I'm logged in by checking with my backend. When I console log the 'auth', it shows:

Updated auth: {accessToken: 'eyJhb......_ucf70'}

2. Once redirected to the chat page, I get a 401 Unauthorized error when trying to fetch chats. This suggests that the 'auth' state, which should contain my accessToken, is now undefined.

For reference, the console.log inside useAxiosPrivate.js shows:

this is the auth undefined

Login.jsx:

```
//... other imports
import axios from '../api/axios';
import useAuth from '../hooks/useAuth';

//...(rest of code)

import { Link, useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';


const LOGIN_URL = '/login';


const Login = () => {
    const { auth, setAuth } = useAuth()
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    const location = useLocation()
    const from = location.state?.from?.pathname || "/chat"


  
    const [user, setUser] = useState('');
    const [pwd, setPwd] = useState('');
    const [errMsg, setErrMsg] = useState('');


    useEffect(() => {
        userRef.current.focus();
      }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
      setErrMsg('');
    }, [user, pwd]);

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log("Updated auth:", auth);
  }, [auth]);


      
    useEffect(() => {
      if(auth && auth.accessToken){
        navigate('/chat', { replace: true });
      }
    }, [auth, navigate]);


    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

    

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('username', user);
    formData.append('password', pwd);

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        LOGIN_URL,
        formData,
        {
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
          withCredentials: true,
        }
      );
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response?.data));
        
        
        const accessToken = response?.data.access_token;
        setAuth({accessToken})
        
        setUser('');
        setPwd('')
        setErrMsg('');
        
        
    
    
    } catch (err) {
      if (!err?.response) {
        //setErrMsg('No Server Response');    removing for now
        console.log(err);
      } else if (err.response?.status === 400) {
        setErrMsg('Missing Username or Password');
      } else if (err.response?.status === 401) {
        setErrMsg('Unauthorized');
      } else {
        console.log(err);
        setErrMsg('Login Failed');
      }
      errRef.current.focus();
    }
  };



  return (
    // JSX for login

  )
}

export default Login
```

chatpage.jsx:

```
//... other imports
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import useRefreshToken from "../hooks/useRefreshToken";
import useAxiosPrivate from "../hooks/useAxiosPrivate";



const ChatPage = () =>  {
  const axiosPrivate = useAxiosPrivate();

  const refresh = useRefreshToken();
  
  //... unrelated code

  useEffect(() => {
    
    const fetchChats = async () => {
        
        try {
            const response = await axiosPrivate.get('/chat/getchats');
            
            if (response.status === 200) {
                
                setChats(response.data.map(chat => chat.chat_name));

            } else {
                console.error("Error fetching the chats:", response.data);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("There was a problem fetching chats:", error);
        }
    };

    fetchChats();
  }, []); // Empty dependency array ensures this useEffect runs only once

  
  //... rest of ChatPage component 


////////////////////
```

axios.js:

```
import axios from "axios"

const BASE_URL ='http://127.0.0.1:8000'

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL
})

export const axiosPrivate = axios.create({
    baseURL: BASE_URL,
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}, 
    withCredentials:true
})

///////////////////
```

AuthProvider.jsx:

```
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext({});

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState({});

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ auth, setAuth }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default AuthContext;
////////////////////
```

useAuth.jsx:

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import AuthContext from "../context/AuthProvider";

const useAuth = () => {
    const { auth } = useContext(AuthContext);
    return useContext(AuthContext);

}

export default useAuth;

//////////////////
```

useAxiosPrivate.jsx

```
import { axiosPrivate } from "../api/axios";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import useRefreshToken from "./useRefreshToken";
import useAuth from "./useAuth";

const useAxiosPrivate = () => {
    const refresh = useRefreshToken();
    const { auth } = useAuth();

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`this is the auth ${auth.AccessToken}`)
        const requestIntercept = axiosPrivate.interceptors.request.use(
            config => {
                if (!config.headers['Authorization']){
                    config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${auth.AccessToken}`;
                }
                return config;
            }, (error) => Promise.reject(error)
        )

        const responseIntercept = axiosPrivate.interceptors.response.use(
            response => response, 
            async (error) => {
                const prevRequest = error?.config;
                if (error?.response?.status ===403 && !prevRequest?.sent) {
                    prevRequest.sent = true;
                    const newAccessToken = await refresh()
                    prevRequest.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${newAccessToken}`;
                    return axiosPrivate(prevRequest);
                }
                return Promise.reject(error);
            }
        )
        return () => {
            axiosPrivate.interceptors.request.eject(requestIntercept)
            axiosPrivate.interceptors.response.eject(responseIntercept)

        }

    },[auth, refresh]) 

    return axiosPrivate;
}

export default useAxiosPrivate;

//////////////////////
```

App.jsx:

```
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom"

import HomePage from "./components/HomePage"
import ChatPage from "./components/ChatPage"
import SignUp from "./components/SignUp"
import Login from "./components/Login"
import Layout from "./components/Layout"

import RequireAuth from "./components/RequireAuth"



function App() {
  return (
    
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route path='/' element = {<HomePage/>} />
          <Route path='/login' element = {<Login/>} />
          <Route path='/signup' element = {<SignUp/>} />

          {/* this is a protected route */} 
          <Route element = {<RequireAuth />} >
            <Route path='/chat' element = {<ChatPage/>} />
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </Routes> 
  )
}

export default App;
/////////////////////
```

main.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthProvider } from './context/AuthProvider';

import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-tailwind/react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ThemeProvider>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <AuthProvider>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/*" element={<App />} />
          </Routes>
        </AuthProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
////////////////////
```

Answer (score 0):

to me it looks like you are returning the wrong value in "useAuth.js"

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import AuthContext from "../context/AuthProvider";

const useAuth = () => {
    const { auth } = useContext(AuthContext);
    return auth ; // Not: return useContext(AuthContext)    
}

export default useAuth;
```

Comment: thank you! that was the issue, I also had a variable name.